# Structure of ideals in the product of two rings

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

> $R$ and $S$ are two rings. Let $J$ be an ideal in $R\times S$. Then there are $I_{1}$, ideal of $R$, and $I_{2}$, ideal of $S$ such that $J=I_{1}\times I_{2}$.

For me it's obvious why $\left\{ r\in R\mid \left(r,s\right)\in J\text{ for some } s\in S\right\}$ is an ideal of $R$ (and the same for $S$) so I can prove $J$ is a subset of the product of two ideals and also that the product of these two ideals is an ideal.

But I can't see how to prove equality without assuming existence of unity or commutativity. Trying basically to show that if $\left(r,s\right)\in J$ then also $\left(r,0\right),\left(0,s\right)\in J$.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 29):

If you have an identity, multiplying by $(1_R,0)$ and $(0,1_S)$ will help.  If you don't, then the result need not be true.  E.g. if you put the zero product on the abelian group $\mathbb Z_2\oplus \mathbb Z_2$, then the ideal ($=$subgroup) generated by $(\overline 1,\overline 1)$ is a counterexample.

Comment: I dont exactly understand what "put the zero product on the abelian group" mean. can you explain please? and Thank you for your quick answer =)

Comment: @IIJ: If $(G,+)$ is an abelian group and you define a multiplication by $a\cdot b =0$ for all $a,b\in G$, then $G$ becomes a ring with the zero product.  E.g. $\mathbb Z_2$ with the zero product has the usual addition, but $\overline 0\cdot \overline 0 =\overline 1\cdot \overline 0 =\overline 0\cdot \overline 1=\overline 1\cdot\overline 1 = \overline 0$.

Comment: Oh yes! Thank you!. have a great day!

Comment: Hello Sir, I have a question, what if J in this case is prime ideal? how do we prove that its a product of one prime ideal of R and S itself or product of R and prime ideal of S? I came up with  the R*S/J being integral domain.. But I'm stuck. Thankyou

Comment: @d13: Sorry, I don't understand your comment.

Answer (score 29):

Let us assume that $R$ has an identity element $1_R$.

Let $I$ be a two-sided ideal of $R\times S$. Define $I_R = \left\{r \in R: \, \exists s \in S \, \, \, \text{s.t.} \, \,  (r,s) \in I \right\}$ and similarly $I_S = \left\{s \in S: \, \exists r \in R \, \, \, \text{s.t.} \, \,  (r,s) \in I \right\}$. Then $I_R, I_S$ are ideals of $R,S$ and $I \subset I_R \times I_S$.

Now take $r \in I_R$ and $s \in I_S$. We will show that $(r,s) \in I$. By definition there is some $s' \in S$ such that $(r,s') \in I$. Similarly there is some $r' \in R$ such that $(r',s) \in I$. Since $I$ is a two-sided ideal, we have that
$(1_R,s)(r,s') = (r,ss') \in I$. Similarly, $(r',s)(1_R,s') = (r',ss') \in I$. Hence $(r-r',0) \in I$ and so $(r', s) + (r - r', 0) = (r,s) \in I$.

**Remark:** As we see, all we need is that only one of $R,S$ has an identity element.

Comment: Wonderful remark!

Answer (score 13):

*Lemma.* Let $(A_i)_{i=1,\ldots,n}$ be a (finite) family of rings with $1$. Then ideals of $A = \prod_{i=1}^n A_i$ are of the form $I_1 \times \ldots\times I_n$, where $I_i$ is an ideal of $A_i$ for each $i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$.

*Proof.* By induction on $n$, the cases $n\in\{0,1\}$ being trivial, one sees that it suffices to prove the assertion for $n=2$. Let $K$ be an ideal of a product $A\times B$ of two rings with $1$, and denote by $p : A\times B\to A$ and $q : A\times B\to B$ the two canonical projections. Then $I = p(K)$ (resp. $J = q(K)$) is an ideal of $A$ (resp. of $B$.), because the image of an ideal under a surjective ring homomorphism is an ideal. Obviously $K\subseteq I\times J$. To show the inverse inclusion, let $(a,b)\in I\times J$. Then $(a,b') \in K$ and $(a',b)\in K$ for some $(a',b')\in A\times B$. Then $(a,b) = (1,0)(a,b') + (0,1)(a',b) \in K$. $\square$

Answer (score 9):

The answer of Manos can be generalized to a characterization (references at the end):

Let $R,S$ be rings (not necessarily with identity element). Consider the product $R\times S$. We say that an ideal of the product is a **subproduct ideal** if it is of the form $I\times J$ with $I$ ideal of $R$, $J$ ideal of $S$. Now fix $R$. The following assertions are equivalent:

1. For all rings $S$, the ideals of $R\times S$ are subproduct ideals.
2. The ideals of $R\times R$ are subproduct ideals.
3. $R$ is a (two-sided) **$e$-ring**, that is, for every element $r\in R$ we have $r\in Rr+rR+RrR$.

(Observe that $Rr+rR+RrR$ may fell short of being the ideal generated by $r$, as it doesn't necessarily include $\mathbb{Z}r$).

Let us prove the theorem:

**3)$\Rightarrow$1)** This is essentially Manos' proof. Given $I$ ideal of $R\times S$, we define
$$I_R:=\{r\in R \ | \ \exists s\in S, (r,s)\in I\}, \ I_S:=\{s\in S \ | \ \exists r\in R, (r,s)\in I\}.$$
That $I\subseteq I_R\times I_S$ is straightforward. Pick $(r,s)\in I_R\times I_S$. Then there are $r'\in R$, $s'\in S$ such that $(r,s'),(r',s)\in I$. By hypothesis we know that there exist $a,b,u_i,v_i\in R$ such that $r=ar+rb+\sum_iu_irv_i$. Since $I$ is an ideal, $(ar,0)=(a,0)(r,s')$, $(rb,0)=(r,s')(b,0)$ and $(u_irv_i,0)=(u_i,0)(r,s')(v_i,0)$ are in $I$, and this implies $(r,0)\in I$. Similarly $(r',0)\in I$, and thus $(r,s)=(r-r',0)+(r',s)\in I$. Therefore $I=I_R\times I_S$.

**1)$\Rightarrow$2)** Trivial.

**2)$\Rightarrow$3)** Pick $r\in R$ and consider the ideal $I$ generated by $(r,r)$ in $R\times R$. By hypothesis we have $I=J\times K$, with $J,K$ ideals of $R$. Since $(r,r)\in J\times K$ we have $(r,0)\in J\times K=I=$Id$(r,r)$, what means that there exist $z\in\mathbb{Z}$, $a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2,u_i,v_i,x_i,y_i\in R$ such that
$$r=zr+a_1r+rb_1+\sum_iu_irv_i, \ 0=zr+a_2r+rb_2+\sum_ix_iry_i.$$
The key here is that $z$ is the same in both equations, so we can equate by $zr$ to get $r=(a_1-a_2)r+r(b_1-b_2)+\sum_i c_ird_i\in Rr+rR+RrR$.

---

**EDITED:** Of course, rings with identity are $e$-rings. Another interesting class of $e$-rings is that of von Neumann regular rings.

---

Observe that we have a similar (less convoluted, more restrictive) version for one-sided ideals:

1. For all rings $S$, the left (resp. right) ideals of $R\times S$ are a subproduct of left (resp. right) ideals.
2. The left (resp. right) ideals of $R\times R$ are a subproduct of left (resp. right) ideals.
3. $R$ is a left (resp. right) **$e$-ring**, that is, for every element $r\in R$ exists a "local unit" $e_r\in R$ such that $e_r\cdot r=r$ (resp. $r\cdot e_r=r$).

The proof is analogous.

---

The "e-ring" and "subproduct" denotations, results and proofs are taken from (anyone of)

1. [*Commutative rngs*](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2265798). Anderson (2006). Proposition 3.1.
2. [*Ideals in direct products of commutative rings*](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/bulletin-of-the-australian-mathematical-society/article/ideals-in-direct-products-of-commutative-rings/E05E687B5A34159873E5E855CB4DE8AF). Anderson, Kintzinger (2008). Theorem 2.
3. [*Subgroups of direct products of groups, ideals and subrings of direct products of rings, and Goursat's lemma*](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2508141). Anderson, Camillo (2009). Theorem 10.

Note that references 1) and 3) are to papers published in books. Reference 3) is really interesting, since it determines **all** ideals (and subrings!) of a direct product of two rings, for any two rings (theorem 11).

Answer (score 0):

Let $L$ be an ideal of the direct product $R \times S$.
Let us define
$$
I=\{a \in R \mid(a, b) \in L \text { for some } b \in S\}
$$
and
$$
J=\{b \in S \mid(a, b) \in L \text { for some } a \in R\} \text {. }
$$
We claim that $I$ and $J$ are ideals of $R$ and $S$ respectively.
Let $a, a^{\prime} \in I$, then there exist $b, b^{\prime} \in S$ such that $(a, b),\left(a^{\prime}, b^{\prime}\right) \in L$.
Since $L$ is an ideal, we have.
$$
(a, b)+\left(a^{\prime}, b^{\prime}\right)=\left(a+a^{\prime}, b+b\right) \in L.
$$
It follows that $a+a^{\prime} \in I$.
Moreover, for any $r \in R$.
$$
(r, 0)\cdot (a, b)=(r a, 0) \in L,
$$
because $L$ is an ideal.
Thus $r a \in I$, and $I$ is an ideal of $R$.
Analogously, $J$ is an ideal of $S$. We now prove that $L=I \times J$.

,,$L\subset I\times J"$: Let $(a, b) \in L$. Then, according to the definitions of $I$ and $J$, we have that $a is \in I$ and $b is \in J$.\

,,$L\supseteq I\times J"$: Let $(a, b) be \in I \times J$. Since $a is \in I$, there exists $b^{\prime} \in S$ such that $\left(a, b^{\prime}\right) \in L$.
Since $b is \in J$, there is also $a^{\prime} \in R$ such that $\left(a^{\prime}, b\right) is \in L$.
Since $L$ is an ideal of $R \times S$, we have.
$$
(1_R,0)\left(a, b^{\prime}\right)=(a, 0) \in L \quad\text { and }\quad (0,1_S)\left(a^{\prime}, b\right)=(0, b) \in L .
$$
It follows that
$$
(a, b)=(a, 0)+(0, b) \in L .
$$
Therefore, $I \times J \subset L$.
Putting the findings together, we get $L=I \times J$ as required. $\square$