# Confusion of a definition on Atiyah and MacDonald

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

This question may be really stupid and several posts related to my questions have been posted, but none of them addressed my confusion. In page 20 of Atiyah and Macdonald, if I am reading it correctly, they say something as follows.

Let $A$ be a commutative ring and if $A=\prod_{i=1}^{n}A_{i}$ is a direct product of rings $A_{i}$, then the set of all elements of $A$ of the form $$(0,\cdots, 0,a_{i},0,\cdots,0),$$ where $a_{i}\in A_{i}$ is an ideal $\mathfrak{a}_{i}$ of $A$.

I am confused by this definition. So the set is the set of all the elements $(a_{1},0,0,\cdots,0)$ with $a_{1}\in A_{1}$, $(0,a_{2},0,0,\cdots,0)$ with $a_{2}\in A_{2}$, and so on until $(0,0,\cdots,0,a_{n})$ with $a_{n}\in A_{n}$.

Then, why there is still a subscript for $\mathfrak{a}_{i}$? Why does this ideal still depend on the choice of $i$? I don't know if this question is obvious, but it is pretty confusing to me..

Comment: You've misunderstood the definition. $\mathfrak{a}_{i}$ consists of all tuples which have coordinate zero except in the $i$th position. That is, $\mathfrak{a}_{i} = \{(0, 0, \ldots, 0, a_{i}, 0, \ldots, 0) \mid a_{i} \in A_{i}\}$.

Comment: @AlexWertheim ah... ok... sorry for my dumb question.

Comment: Nothing to be sorry for, and your question is not dumb. Glad everything is clear now!

Comment: @AlexWertheim Thank you for your nice word :)

Comment: I believe the intention is to take $i$ fixed here; i.e. the only non-zero coordinates occur in the $i$-th coordinate for a fixed $i$. Otherwise the set you describe isn't even closed under addition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The index $i$ is fixed, it doesn't run from $1$ to $n$. So the precise definition is $$ \mathfrak{a}_i = \{(0, \dots, 0, a_i, 0, \dots, 0) : a_i \in A_i \}.$$ [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101214) is a more general discussion of ideals in product rings.

Comment: Great. Thank you for the further reference!