# One sided ideals of a semisimple ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, direct-product, semi-simple-rings

Let $A$ be a semisimple ring. I'm wondering whether all ideals of $A$ are two sided. I know that all semisimple rings are both left and right semisimple. And, since $A$ is a semisimple module over itself, we can write
$$A=\bigoplus_{i=1}^n S_i $$
where $S_i=A/m_i$ for some maximal ideal. Thus,
$$A=\prod_{i=1}^n A/m_i. $$
I believe that every two sided ideal should be a direct sum of the simple submodules, but what can be said of specifically one sided ideals? Since $A$ need not be commutative, I don't believe that every ideal necessarily is two sided, but I'm not sure how to go about finding the one sided ideals.

Comment: No, it's not true that all ideals are two-sided. For example, $A = M_n(k)$ has interesting left and right ideals (hint: it has a natural action on $k^n$, pick any nonzero vector and consider the kernel of the action on this vector).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan In your example, $A$ is certainly simple, but is it necessarily semisimple?

Comment: Yes. Every ring which is both simple and artinian is semisimple. By Artin-Wedderburn these are exactly the rings of the form $M_n(D)$ where $D$ is a division ring. This ring has a unique simple module, namely $D^n$, and every module is a direct sum of copies of it. This is actually enough to tell you what the left and right ideals are, using the fact that a left resp. right ideal is a submodule with respect to left resp. right multiplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm not sure how to go about finding the one sided ideals.

By Artin-Wedderburn, $A\cong\prod_{i=1}^k M_{n_i}(D_i)$ for some positive integers $k, n_i$ and division rings $D_i$.

The right ideals of $A$ are [products of right ideals of each factor](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2517049/29335).

The right ideals of a matrix ring [can be completely described](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/26830/29335).

Putting these two things together, you can say you have a description of right ideals of $A$.

> I don't believe that every ideal necessarily is two sided,

That would be correct. For example, $\begin{bmatrix}k&k \\ 0&0\end{bmatrix}$ is a proper right ideal of $M_2(k)$ which is not a left ideal.

In fact, the only semisimple rings in which one-sided ideals are all two-sided are finite products of division rings.